# MUI - Change specific day color in DatePicker

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-redux, material-ui

Have anyone added events to MUI `DatePicker`? Or someone know to change background of selected day? For example change color of the selected day? Or add a birthday to selected day?

[image: Edit State] [image: My Date Picker]

My code:

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import AdapterDateFns from "@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns";
import LocalizationProvider from "@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider";
import StaticDatePicker from "@mui/lab/StaticDatePicker";
import isWeekend from "date-fns/isWeekend";

export default function DatePicker() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<Date | null>(new Date());
  console.log(value);
  return (
    <div>
      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
        <StaticDatePicker<Date>
          orientation="portrait"
          openTo="day"
          value={value}
          shouldDisableDate={isWeekend}
          onChange={(newValue) => {
            setValue(newValue);
          }}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
        />
      </LocalizationProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a custom [`PickersDay`](https://mui.com/api/pickers-day/#css) component and override the selected day background color like this:

```
import DatePicker from "@mui/lab/DatePicker";
import PickersDay, {
  PickersDayProps,
  pickersDayClasses
} from "@mui/lab/PickersDay";

const renderWeekPickerDay = (
  date: Date,
  selectedDates: Array<Date | null>,
  pickersDayProps: PickersDayProps<Date>
) => {
  return (
    <PickersDay
      {...pickersDayProps}
      sx={{
        [`&&.${pickersDayClasses.selected}`]: {
          backgroundColor: "green"
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Then override the `renderDay` callback in `DatePicker`:

```
<DatePicker
  renderDay={renderWeekPickerDay}
  {...}
/>
```

**Edit:** If you want to highlight multiple days with different styles:

```
type HighlightedDay = {
  date: Date;
  styles: React.CSSProperties;
};
const highlightedDays: HighlightedDay[] = [
  {
    date: birthday,
    styles: { color: "red" }
  },
  {
    date: addDays(new Date(), 6),
    styles: { /* ... */ }
  },
  {
    date: addDays(new Date(), 9),
    styles: { /* ... */ }
  },
  {
    date: addDays(new Date(), 12),
    styles: { /* ... */ }
  }
];

const renderWeekPickerDay = (
  date: Date,
  selectedDates: Array<Date | null>,
  pickersDayProps: PickersDayProps<Date>
) => {
  const matchedStyles = highlightedDays.reduce((a, v) => {
    return isSameDay(date, v.date) ? v.styles : a;
  }, {});

  return (
    <PickersDay
      {...pickersDayProps}
      sx={{
        ...matchedStyles,
        [`&&.${pickersDayClasses.selected}`]: {
          backgroundColor: "green"
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

### Reference

- https://mui.com/components/date-picker/#customized-day-rendering

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution i have been looking for. I have an additional question. Why is "const birthday = addDays(new Date(), 3);" setting the date to 10/04/2021 ?

Comment: And what should i do if i want to change color on multiple days ?

Comment: @kacper3671 see my updated answer. About your first comment, check your system time by logging `new Date()`, `addDays()` works as expected on my machine.

Comment: This solution is great. I have been running into an issue where typescript says property 'selected' is missing in type... Does anyone know how I would fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try importing `DatePicker` and check.

```
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import DayPicker from 'react-day-picker';
import 'react-day-picker/lib/style.css';
import 'bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css';
```

Use it in your code something like below:

```
<DatePicker
     selected={this.state.fromDate}
     onChange={this.handleFilterFromMonthChange}
     dateFormat="MM/yyyy"
     showMonthYearPicker
     className="form-control"
/>
```

When you install the datepicker, in node modules you will find file

`react-datepicker.css` ie. `react-datepicker -> dist -> react-datepicker.css` ,

`daterangepicker.css` ie. `bootstrap-daterangepicker -> daterangepicker.css`

Maybe you can do few changes in these files and you might get what you are searching for. You can try this and let me know whether it solves or not.

If not then I will try to find different way to solve your issue