# Typescript error when using pickers day classes from Mui

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have code that changes the selected day on Mui datepicker.

Specifically I referenced this overflow [MUI - Change specific day color in DatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69477377/mui-change-specific-day-color-in-datepicker)

The solution in there worked great. But recently I had to update dependencies and now typescript is giving property selected does not exist on type {}.

I've googled that error and found a lot of information about explicitly setting the type. But while the examples it seems straightforward, I can't see how I would do it in this instance. I have read a lot on the mui docs, and while I see how sx changes the class, since this is on a mui specific `pickersDayClasses.selected` I'm not sure how to handle that.

Following is the code:

```
const renderWeekPickerDay = (
date: Date,
selectedDatesL Array<Date | null>,
    pickersDayProps: PickersDayProps<Date>
) => {
const highlightedDateColor = getColor() === primary ? "#008000" : "#FF0000"

<PickersDay
{...pickersDayProps }
sx = {{
    [`&&.${pickersDayClasses.selected}`]: {
        backgroundColor: "highlightedDateColor"
    }
}}
/>
)
<DesktopDatePicker
renderDay={renderWeekPickerDay}
```

Comment: Can you share the path where you `pickersDayClasses` importing from? The import path should be `import { pickersDayClasses } from '@mui/x-date-pickers'`

Comment: Running an npm install for mui/x-date-pickers and importing it there did solve the problem. Before I had import PickersDay, { PickersDayProps, pickersDayClasses } from "@mui/lab/PickersDay"
Thank you! If you post this as an answer I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested MUI `x-date-pickers` at version `^6.9.2`. The import path should be

```
import { pickersDayClasses } from '@mui/x-date-pickers'
```

To edit the styling of the selected day you can use `pickersDayClasses` combined with `slotProps`.

```
import { DatePicker , pickersDayClasses } from '@mui/x-date-pickers'

<DatePicker 
    slotProps={{
        day: {
          sx: {
            [`&.${pickersDayClasses.selected}`]: {
              bgcolor: 'red !important', //replace it with any color you want
            },
          },
        },
        },
      }}
  />
```

Tip: Use `!important` CSS rule, If MUI overrides your custom styling. Generally, you can find in `devtools` if your custom styling is getting overridden by another styling.

Here is the list of [DatePicker slots](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-picker/#slots) you can individually edit or style.

Comment: Thanks, for those reading this that didn't see my above comment. A previous version I was using imported PickersDay, { PickersDayProps, pickersDayClasses } from '@mui/lab/PickersDay'. After following Simran's advice and running npm install @mui/x-date-pickers and then importing pickersDayClasses from there it got rid of error typescript was giving on the "selected" portion of the pickersDay class.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to handle the renderDay and renderInput props being removed in mui/x-day-pickers? They were there when it was mui/lab but it forces an update.

Comment: Can you share the current usage of `renderDay` and `renderInput` in your DatePicker? I will replace it with newer version usage.

Comment: So I was able to change renderInput to slotProps={{ texfield like it says in the migration guides and got that working.

But the renderDay I tried using slots={{ day: renderWeekPickerDay }} but it gives me an error on day saying can't be assigned. I edited my answer to show more how the renderWeekPickerDay is a function that returns the value.

I also just tried putting sx = {{
    [`&&.${pickersDayClasses.selected}`]: {
        backgroundColor: "highlightedDateColor"
    }
}} on the DatePicker component and that didn't work either.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: Wow thank you! I was trying so many different things to no luck. Based on the migration documents I thought it would go in slots not slotprops. And then I was trying sx right on the datepicker and textfield. Never thought to do slot props with day and then sx inside. Thank you again!